# Print all decimal digits of long double variable

Tags: c++, gcc, double

I figured out that `double` type on my machine corresponds to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) Wikipedia article, and `long double` corresponds to this text: [x86 Extended Precision Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format).

That's why `floor(52/log2(10))` or 15 digits of `double` should be correct and `floor(63/log2(10))` or 19 digits of `long double` are trusted.

The code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    double d=0.1;
    long double ld=0.1;

    std::cout.precision(19);
    std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::scientific);

    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    std::cout << ld << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

gives the output:

```
1.0000000000000000555e-01
1.0000000000000000555e-01
```

If we set `cout.precision` to 16, the output will be:

```
1.0000000000000001e-01
1.0000000000000001e-01
```

It's allright, that 17th digit of `double` in 1st output and 16th digit of `double` in second output is incorrect. But why is it incorrect for `long double`? Is there a way to get all 19 correct digits of `long double` variables?

If I try `printf("%.19Le\n",ld);` for long double, I get exactly the same result.

I use OpenSUSE 12.1 and g++ 4.6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `0.1` literal constant is not a long double, it is probably a double .

You may want to initialize `ld` with

```
 long double ld = (long double) 1.0 / (long double) 10.0;
```

So that the division involves two long double operands, so hopefully is done in long double (I am not sure of that, you have to double check the appropriate C++ standards).

And you probably want to compile with GCC supporting the latest standard. With a GCC 4.7 I would suggest to compile with `g++ -Wall -std=c++11` but with your 4.6 you may need to say `-std=c++0x`

Comment: It's a double. Floats have `f` on the end and long doubles `L` (with case not mattering, of course).

Comment: Thanks! `(long double) 1.0 / (long double) 10.0` works without any `-std` options. `long double ld=0.1L;` also works.